# Android: Executor.execute fails for some reason

Tags: android, threadpool, executor

In the run() method of a thread, earlier I had this code snippet:

```
updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read,write,this.clientSocket,input,out));
```

It used to work. But when I call it using Executors, it fails:

```
                    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
                    executor.execute(new updateUIThread(read,write,this.clientSocket,input,out));
```

There's no response with the above code.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Because your executor knows nothing about `updateConversationHandler`

Comment: Alex, I didn't understand. Updateconversationhandler is of type Handler. How does it affect the Executor ?

Comment: It says, "Only the original thread that created a View hierarchy can touch its Views."

Answer (score 0):

use like this:
make your constructor according to your parameter:

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
            private String msg;

```
        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved. Removed all instances of 'Toasts' and 'text.setText()'. Works properly now.

The Android team must make a list of such errors and list them at their site. Something like "Error message -- Possible Cause -- Solution". That way.